# how to use Intent to send 'event' between two classes?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to add the data that i want to send to my Intent.

but i can't find any code example that send and receive the Intent that i defined.
I only finding example that do it with ActivityStart - but my classes that i want to use are not and activity - just a simple java class.

How can i do it ?

Comment: If you don't want to start an activity are you targetting a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I want to send some 'status change' to other class that will be the listener to the status change event

Comment: Can you provide some sample code we can have alternative to achieve same.
As intent are to be communicated within components like activity, broadcast receiver, service.
You can pass data to your class from one of obove components by using constructor or setter methods

Comment: To find a tutorial on that search for BroadcastReceiver and Intent. You most likely would be going for a Local BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Sending Intents are only for Android Application classes like activity, services broad cast receiver, etc only. You have to give your own problem may be an interface is what you real need!

Comment: "how to use Intent to send 'event' between two classes in android?" -- you don't, usually. "I want to send some 'status change' to other class that will be the listener to the status change event " -- reorganize your code into RxJava chains. Or, use an event bus (which could use `LocalBroadcastManager`, which happens to use `Intent`). Or, just implement a simple listener/callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a method that has a `Data` parameter and send your data using it, intents doesn't send data between classes bro, take this example, here I want to send data from MainActivity, to class A:
** **MainActivity:**

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.setData(data);
```

** **ClassA:**

```
public void setData(Data data){
    this.data = data;
}
```